# ionic cap add android npm ERR

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic6

After running `ionic cap add android` from https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app/deploying-mobile had npm ERR!

```
 Found: @capacitor/core@3.3.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@capacitor/core
npm ERR!   @capacitor/core@"3.3.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @capacitor/core@"^3.4.0" from @capacitor/android@3.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@capacitor/android
npm ERR!   @capacitor/android@"3.4.1" from the root project
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem figure out with next solution
manually change verions in `package.json`.

Change version `"@capacitor/core": "VERSION"`,
**VERSION** should be the same as `@capacitor/android` **VERSION**

In my case set up `"@capacitor/core": "3.4.1"`, because  `@capacitor/android@"3.4.1"`

Comment: Wanted to add for some other poor soul struggling that for me while `@capacitor/core` and `@capacitor/core` were matching - `@capactior/cli` was not and I didn't notice as it was at the bottom of the `package.json` under the `devDependencies`. Once I changed such that all were matching everything was grand.